# Build PHP extension of Saxon for Windows

Tags: php, saxon

I need to use XSLT 2.0 with PHP on Windows for a work, and after a few research, it seems that the best way to achieve it is to use the saxon-C of Saxonica.

I followed the official documentation  until this point :

> The PHP extension has not yet been built. It can be built using the PHP source. [...] To build the PHP extension yourself please see the Saxon-C-API Visual Studio 2008 project included in the installation (e.g. 'C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHEC1.1.0\Saxon-C-API').

I looked at the file and there are some .h and .cpp files and the config.w32 file, so I tried to build the extension according to this documentation :

http://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/build-php-extension-on-windows/

But I have some error during the process.

Is it the right way to perform it ? Or is there a better way to do it ?

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm not a PHP pro.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your post. We would like to assist you in getting Saxon/C PHP extension working on windows. Please can you add the errors you are seeing? Also what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I have created the following bug issue to keep track of progress of the PHP extension of Saxon/C on Windows: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3705

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer! I'm using PHP 7.0.27. When I try to build the extension, I add the modules with the command line "--add-modules-dir-dir=C:\path\to\the\saxon.C.API\folder", it seems to work but after I can't enable the saxon extension with "--enable-saxon" or "--with-saxon" because it don't appear as a valid option ("unknow option --enable-saxon; please try configuer.js --help for a list of valid option"). I hope that I succed to be clear. Again thank you for your help!

Comment: For PHP 7.0.27 the following guide might be more helpful: https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild
I tried building with PHP 7.2 using the following guide: https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2
This guide led me to use the github page: https://github.com/Microsoft/php-sdk-binary-tools which got me further in the build process. Getting some build errors in the C++ code.

Comment: Updated https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3705

Comment: According to this documentation, I'm not sure to understand when I have to "connect" the Saxonica's folder to add the extension and build it. Thank you very much for your help!